# Failed to install Cloudera-manager-agent

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I was installing cloudera manager in my machine running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS xenial OS. when I type `sudo apt-get install cloudera-manager-agent` 
I got following on my command line

`root@chinni:/home/solomon# apt-get install cloudera-manager-agent
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cloudera-manager-agent : Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`

Please give me fix

Thanks and Regards
M.S.Krishna

Answer (score 0):

First try `sudo apt-get install -f`  to fix broken package. If not works then try to remove by
Purgeing the installed package by `sudo apt-get purge cloudera-manager-agent`. 
Then clean your apt cache file by running

`sudo apt-get autoclean 
 sudo apt-get clean cache`

then update and upgrade your package manager by running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

then again install your packege by `sudo apt-get install cloudera-manager-agent`

Hope this will work!!

Answer (score 0):

When I type `apt-get purge Cloudera-manager-agent`
Got following

`root@chinni:/home/solomon#  apt-get purge Cloudera-manager-agent
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Package 'Cloudera-manager-agent' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.`

when I type `sudo apt-get autoclean`

Got following

`root@chinni:/home/solomon# sudo apt-get autoclean 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done`

When I type `sudo apt-get clear cache`

Got followig

`root@chinni:/home/solomon#  sudo apt-get clear cache
E: Invalid operation clear`

When I type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Got following

`E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/dae248f756e160fd915d49993b50c904e511bf59424df660d6946bc266992370

E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/7482a22fa7637f6a15b2ffe45c0347c52e8785174fae3623d97e0e1bcee3ba3f

E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/60aed3a96f8007aea276e6a21e4a3b0d2bde0560605d0a6f044ca895305aeb1d

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`
 When I typed `apt-get install Cloudera-manager-agent`

Got the following

`root@chinni:/home/solomon# apt-get install Cloudera-manager-agent
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
the distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cloudera-manager-agent : Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`

Any fixes?